# Cleanup String: Replace consecutive nonalphanum Character with single seperator

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a string, that need to be formatted:

- keep alphanumeric letters
- replace one or more non-aplhanum characters with a single separator

I came up with this:

```
string Format( string str , string separator )
{
    if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( str ) )
        return string.Empty;

    var words = new List<string>();
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach( var c in str.ToCharArray() )
    {
        if( char.IsLetterOrDigit( c ) )
        {
            sb.Append( c );
        }
        else if( sb.Length > 0 )
        {
            words.Add( sb.ToString() );
            sb.Clear();
        }
    }

    if( sb.Any() )
        words.Add( sb.ToString() );

    return string.Join( seperator , words );
}
```

Is there a better/more-linq-like/shorter/more performant solution (*without* using regex) than this?

Comment: Why, **without regex** ? also more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could eliminate the need for the list and the join if you keep track if the previous character was non-alphanumeric so you know when to append the separator to the `StringBuilder`.  Also `StringBuilder` doesn't have a `Any` method that I know of, so `sb.Count > 0` is likely what you want.

Comment: This code can not compile, string.Join expect string, there is no method Any() for string builder.

Comment: "there's a rat in sep**arat**or", as my English teacher used to say...

Comment: Maybe your `StringBuilder.Any` extension is not efficient, does it always use [`StringBuilder.ToString`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,5a97da49a158a3c9,references)? That's an expensive call in a loop

Comment: @TimSchmelter It has "rat", but not "arat".

Comment: @TimSchmelter there's **a** rat in separator ;)

Comment: Thanks, fixed typos. The two solutions are pretty similar to mine. I was hoping for a linq-like oneliner, that is easy to understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go to the "low level" and use the fact that a string is an `IEnumerable<char>` to use it's `GetEnumerator`

```
string Format(string str, string separator)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder (str.Length);

    using (var e = str.GetEnumerator ())
    {
        while (e.MoveNext ())
        {
            bool hasMoved = true;

            if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit (e.Current))
            {
                while ((hasMoved = e.MoveNext ()) && !char.IsLetterOrDigit (e.Current))
                    ;
                builder.Append (separator);
            }

            if (hasMoved)
                builder.Append (e.Current);
        }
    }

    return builder.ToString ();
}
```

---

Just in case here is a regex version too

```
private static readonly Regex rgx = new Regex(@"[^\w-[_]]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);

string Format (string str, string separator)
{
    return rgx.Replace (str, separator);
}
```

---

**Addendum regarding OP's comment about linq one-liner :**
That's possible but hardly "easy to understand"

*Using anonymous type*

```
string Format (string str, string separator)
{
    return str.Aggregate (new { builder = new StringBuilder (str.Length), prevDiscarded = false }, (state, ch) => char.IsLetterOrDigit (ch) ? new { builder = (state.prevDiscarded ? state.builder.Append (separator) : state.builder).Append (ch), prevDiscarded = false } : new { state.builder, prevDiscarded = true }, state => (state.prevDiscarded ? state.builder.Append (separator) : state.builder).ToString ());
}
```

*Same thing using a Tuple instead*

```
string Format (string str, string separator)
{
    return str.Aggregate (Tuple.Create (new StringBuilder (str.Length), false), (state, ch) => char.IsLetterOrDigit (ch) ? Tuple.Create ((state.Item2 ? state.Item1.Append (separator) : state.Item1).Append (ch), false) : Tuple.Create (state.Item1, true), state => (state.Item2 ? state.Item1.Append (separator) : state.Item1).ToString ());
}
```

*And with Tuple we can make some helpers to "ease" (so to speak) readability [although it's technically not a one-liner anymore]*

```
//top of file
using State = System.Tuple<System.Text.StringBuilder, bool>;

string Format (string str, string separator)
{
    var initialState = Tuple.Create (new StringBuilder (str.Length), false);

    Func<State, StringBuilder> addSeparatorIfPrevDiscarded = state => state.Item2 ? state.Item1.Append (separator) : state.Item1;
    Func<State, char, State> aggregator = (state, ch) => char.IsLetterOrDigit (ch) ? Tuple.Create (addSeparatorIfPrevDiscarded (state).Append (ch), false) : Tuple.Create (state.Item1, true);
    Func<State, string> resultSelector = state => addSeparatorIfPrevDiscarded (state).ToString ();

    return str.Aggregate (initialState, aggregator, resultSelector);
}
```

What makes it complex is that (IMO) Linq* is not really well suited when "item output" depend on previous (or next) items in the same collection
* *Well Linq doesn't have a problem with that but it's quickly a lot of noise with Func and anonymous types/tuple syntax (maybe C#7.0 will change that a bit)*

In the same flavor, one could also embrace side-effects which allow to have only the bool as state

```
string Format (string str, string separator)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder (str.Length);

    Action<bool> addSeparatorIfPrevDiscarded = prevDiscarded => { if (prevDiscarded) builder.Append (separator); };
    Func<bool, char, bool> aggregator = (prevDiscarded, ch) => {
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit (ch)) {
            addSeparatorIfPrevDiscarded (prevDiscarded);
            builder.Append (ch);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    };

    addSeparatorIfPrevDiscarded (str.Aggregate (false, aggregator));

    return builder.ToString ();
}
```

Comment: Slightly off: this always ends in a separator if `str` ends with something non-alphanumeric.

Comment: @PeterB wasn't exactly sure of the intended behaviour for that point, "instructions" and sample code contradicts each other on that (and nothing that a `Trim` can't solve)

Comment: This skips the first character in every "word" after the first one. For example, `Format("abc...123...XYZ", '-')` returns `abc-23-YZ`.

Comment: @Sphinxxx nice catch ! I've updated the code to take this in consideration

Answer (score 1):

Something like this to avoid the need for a `List<string>` and the use of `string.Join`.  Also it will compile.

```
string Format(string str, char seperator)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        return string.Empty;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool previousWasNonAlphaNum = false;

    foreach (var c in str)
    {
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
        {
            if (previousWasNonAlphaNum && sb.Count > 0)
                sb.Append(seperator);
            sb.Append(c);
        }

        previousWasNonAlphaNum = !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: string is already an `IEnumerable<char>` there's no need for `ToCharArray`

Comment: @Sehnsucht Yeah, just copy and pasted that from the OP's code. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work

```
    string Format(string str, string separator)
    {
        var delimiter = char.Parse(separator);
        var replaced = false;
        var cArray = str.Select(c =>
        {                
            if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) & !replaced)
            {
                replaced = true;
                return delimiter;
            }
            else if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
            {
                replaced = false;                    
            }
            else
            {
                return ' ';
            }
            return c;

        }).ToArray();

        return new string(cArray).Replace(" ","");
    }
```

or you can try this one below

```
   string Format(string str, string separator)
    {
        var delimiter = char.Parse(separator);
        var cArray = str.Select(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) ? delimiter : c).ToArray();
        var wlist = new string(cArray).Split(new string[]{separator}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return string.Join(separator, wlist);
    }
```

Comment: This only converts the nonalphanum chars to the separator, so multiple separators are possible. `abc_?#def` will become `abc---def` for example (the goal would be `abc-def`).

Comment: You could just use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` in `Split` instead of the `Where` after it.  Also no need for the `ToList` since `string.Join` has an overload that takes `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @juharr Thanks for the infromations, I have updated my answer.